# PHP and SimpleXML - Can't Output File Contents

Tags: php, simplexml

Thanks in advance for the help...

I'm trying to use SimpleXML to output the contents of one of my files. In order to find the file, I had to scan a directory, split the contents of a folder up into two arrays, and then select the newest file from one of the arrays.

```
$files = scandir($dir);
$roster = [];
$schedule = [];
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (!(strpos($file, 'roster')===false)) {
        $roster<< $file;
    } else {
        $schedule<< $file;
    }
}
```

Now when I try to use SimpleXML, I can't get anything to show up.

```
 $xml_file = $file;
 $xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_file);
```

(At this point I try to output the information using echo, but no luck.)

Do I need to open and close the file, or is there another crucial step I'm missing?

Comment: What does `print_r($xml);` output?

Comment: Nothing. Also, I've been getting this error "Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity"

Comment: How about `var_dump(file_exists($file));`

Comment: that's returning:  bool(false)

Comment: File doesn't exist. `var_dump($file);` Does it exist in the same location as the PHP script?

Comment: You've got a bunch of syntax errors too. $roster/schedule can't be set to []. Maybe you mean = array()? Also, what's going on with the $roster << $file? I think you meant: `$roster[]=$file`. Lastly, you need to run simple_load_file inside the loop.

Comment: Append the proper path to it or simplexml_Load_file won't know where to find the file.

Comment: okay, new to php. let me see if i can make sense of that get something working.

Comment: if i'm having to look for a file that's regularly changing, how am i to give it specific path?

Comment: Where is the file in relation to the PHP script? ../xmlfiles/myfile.xml

Comment: the file is in "/School/Reports/schedule-20130313-070004.xml" and the script is in "/www/school/schedule.php"

Comment: Therefore you need to call `simplexml_load_file('/School/Reports/'.$file);`

Comment: worked perfectly, thank you for your help! you should put this as the answer, so i can give you proper credit.

Comment: They're just internet points! Of no concern to me. Good luck!

Comment: very kind of you! i appreciate you sharing your php knowledge!